# Set values based on two range values in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm struggling to find a way to phrase this.

I have a spreadsheet with two worksheets "Final" and "Raw". Final has a range where the user can enter an ID into cells C3 through C13.

From there I want to loop through that range until it is empty and use the values to loop through a range in Raw, ultimately pulling the values into a third range on Final.

It would essentially be an inner join if we were talking in SQL terms with a one to many relationship.

I've thought of a few different ways of doing it, including using `application.worksheetfunction.index`, but I'm struggling to think of a way to implement this.

Edit to add code:

```
Dim indexPO As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim endRow As Long

endRow = Sheets(2).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

indexPO = Sheets(1).Cells(2, "C")


Do While Worksheets(1).Cells(i, "C").Value <> ""
    indexPO = indexPO + 1
    Do While Worksheets(2).Cells = indexPO
        Worksheets(1).Cells(i, "A") = Worksheets(2).Cells(i, "A")
        If Worksheets(2).Cells(i, "A") = "" Then
            Exit Do
        End If

    Loop
Loop
```

Range 1
ID
AAAA
BBBB
CCCC

Range2
ID   Description
AAAA  Cow
AAAA  Cow
AAAA  Cow
AAAA  Cow
BBBB  Moose
BBBB  Moose
BBBB  Moose
FFFF  Pig
FFFF  Pig
FFFF  Pig

Desired output

ID   Description
AAAA  Cow
AAAA  Cow
AAAA  Cow
AAAA  Cow
BBBB  Moose
BBBB  Moose
BBBB  Moose

Comment: Can you paste what code you have already attempted? Have you considered VLookup?

Comment: I'd need to have the third range filled with as many records in the second range but with the index from the first range, then I could vlookup the rest. So I need to solve the first step I guess.

Comment: I have to agree with rayzinnz, it sounds like your looking for a multi lookup solution. Perhaps if you provide an example of data along with the expected output, it would better explain your request.

Comment: Ok..tell me if I'm on track with your request since you did mention similarity to inner join. So let's say you have column A and column B with data. Are you wanting to find a match between column A and B and take those matched values and copy them to column C?

Comment: Yes. I want to merge the two ranges so to speak into range C. I'll provide some sample data and desired output in the main post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming Worksheets(1) is your "Final" sheet, and Worksheets(2) is your "Raw" sheet, try this out as a starter:

```
Dim userRangeRow As Long, rawRow As Long, mergedRow As Long
Dim ID As Variant

mergedRow = 3

For userRangeRow = 3 To 13
    ID = Worksheets(1).Cells(userRangeRow, "C").Value
    If ID = "" Then
        Exit For
    End If

    rawRow = 1
    Do While Worksheets(2).Cells(rawRow, 1).Value <> ""
        If Worksheets(2).Cells(rawRow, 1).Value = ID Then
            Worksheets(1).Cells(mergedRow, 1) = Worksheets(2).Cells(rawRow, 1)
            Worksheets(1).Cells(mergedRow, 2) = Worksheets(2).Cells(rawRow, 2)
            mergedRow = mergedRow + 1
        End If
        rawRow = rawRow + 1
    Loop
Next
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. I just needed to offset mergedRow to fit my destination range. Thanks so much!